# Switch statements- grading system

Tags: c, switch-statement

```
#include <stdio.h>

void main() {
  int a, b, c, d, e, f, avg;

  printf("Enter marks of six subjects: ");
  scanf("%d %d %d %d %d %d %d", &a, &b, &c, &d, &e, &f);
  avg = (a + b + c + d + e + f) / 6;
  printf("Average is %d", avg);

  switch (avg) {
    case 10:
      printf("Your grade is 10.");
      break;
    case 9:
      printf("Your grade is 9.");
      break;
    case 8:
      printf("Your grade is 8.");
      break;
    case 7:
      printf("Your grade is 7.");
      break;
    case 6:
      printf("Your grade is 6.");
      break;
    case 5:
      printf("Your grade is 5.");
    default:
      printf("You are fail.");
  }
}
```

After I enter the marks of six subjects, the code is not running, it's neither showing any error message as well.

Comment: Did you try a HelloWorld successfully?

Comment: Just for looking less distracting, could remove all the unneeded empty lines and use https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help to make a decent code representation?

Comment: Did you try entering 6 grades nevertheless? What happens then?

Comment: You are ignoring the return value of scanf at your own risk. I recommend to get into the habit of using it to learn more about what happens in your program.

Comment: Please compile with warnings on, usually done with `-Wall`. That should tell you that you have seven `%d` format speciifers, but only six pointers to result variables. Your program expects seven values, but reading the seventh one will cause undefined behaviour, i.e. trouble.

Answer (score 1):

Problems include

**Not enabling all compiler warnings**

**Mis-match**

`"%d %d %d %d %d %d %d", &a, &b, &c, &d, &e, &f`: 7 specifiers and 6 following arguments.

**Not checking return value of `scanf()`**

```
// scanf("%d %d %d %d %d %d %d", &a, &b, &c, &d, &e, &f);
if (scanf("%d %d %d %d %d %d", &a, &b, &c, &d, &e, &f) != 6) {
  ; // TBD: Handle error, maybe print some error message and exit
}
```

**No break**

```
case 5:
  printf("Your grade is 5.");
  break; // add 
default:
  printf("You are fail.");
```